# List Files in C

Tags: c, unix

I have a simple program that list files written in C.  I'm just wondering what can I add to this code so the files print out in sorted order?  Thanks

```
while ((directory = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
   printf("%s\n", directory->dir_name);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean ? Sorted order ? By name By size ?

Comment: Store the entries, sort them, and then print them out.

Comment: I would like to sort them by the file names.

Comment: @H2CO3 Ok so let him sort.I was not being rude, I apologise if I sounded so. Thats a really sad way to respond to it. It meant nothing personal to you !

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi You weren't rude. I was being sarcastic towards OP since he didn't make the effort clarifying his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have first to store the names in an array, MAXDIRS is the max number of dirs (or you could use `calloc` to allocate dynamically the array)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

char dirs[MAXDIRS][512]; // you have to ensure correct allocation (eg names < 512 chars)
int ndirs = 0; // number of dirs

while ((directory = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
   strcpy(dirs[ ndirs++ ], directory->d_name);
}

// Then sort the directories

// need a sorting function
int comp(void const *a, void const *b) { 
    char const *u = (char const *)a;
    char const *v = (char const *)b;

    return strcmp(u, v);
}

// use qsort to sort the dirs
qsort (dirs, ndirs, sizeof(dirs[0]), comp);
```

`dirs` now contains a sorted array of directories

```
// display

int i;

for (i=0 ; i<ndirs ; i++) {
  printf("%s\n", dirs[i]);
}
```

Comment: OK; my previous comments are not relevant.  Wrapped up into compilable code, the fragments in the answer work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`readdir()` does not guarantee you any sorting order.
If you need the listing in *any* sorted order you will have to write the code for doing it. In short, collect all filenames in a array and then sort that array depending on your criteria of  sorting.

You can use [scandir()](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/scandir.3.html) on linux platform.

Comment: Hi, I would like to sort them by either name or size.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that [`scandir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scandir.html) is a POSIX function.  IIRC, there's a difference between the Mac OS X implementation and the POSIX implementation, but it is present on Mac OS X too.

Comment: @KevenDiuliy: If you want to sort by size too, then you have to use the `stat()` function to get the sizes, and you have to store both name and size, sort by size, and then print accordingly.

Comment: @KevenDiuliy: It seems the only way to answer your Q was to *write the code for you*, Nothing less than written code seems to appease you.Please refrain from making others do *your* job/task & please try to put some effort on solving your own problems. The easy approach of *write code for me* won't help you much in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you lookup qsort() and use that. You'll probably stumble on some other useful sorting APIs provided by your standard library as well.